# How can I read a Microsoft Money data file using .NET?

Tags: import, ofx, quicken

I have a requirement to read and import data from MS Money data file. How can I achieve this? Is there a SDK available?

I would like to have a similar mechanism to read Quicken files too.

Answer (score 6):

With Microsoft discontinuing the MS Money product, I was researching the same issue to try to do a full data export of MS Money data file transaction information.  The best I have been able to come across was a forum posting detailing manipulating the file to be readable via MS Access.  Unfortunately, his method required purchasing a piece of software to "repair" the file to make it openable.  The thread is here: http://www.archivum.info/microsoft.public.money/2007-09/msg00739.html and the text is below.

> Well for $300 bucks + some custom SQL programming I finally found a way
>   to  get out of Money jail. Here is how
>
> 1. Get FileBinReplace utility here http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/script.htm
> 2. Run it as  FileBinReplace *.mny "MSISAM Database" "Standard Jet DB"
> 3. Rename *.mny to *.mdb
> 4. Use AccessFIX tool ($300; search the web for a download link) to repair
>      the MDB file.
>
> Query TRN and TRN_INVOICE tables as
>   needed.
>
> By the way, when I saw the internal
>   database design in Money, I was 
>   literally shocked. That database was
>   surely designed by entry-level
>   database  programmers… students maybe…
>   who had little idea about relational
>   database  design, normalization or
>   efficiency... Just for the record,
>   invoice text  strings (addresses,
>   customer notes, lines item
>   descriptions, etc.. are stored  tin
>   the same table where on-line
>   transactions are stored, invoice
>   headers and  details are stored in the
>   same table!!! you get the idea about
>   who and how  designed it)

I would hope since MS is no longer going to support the product or data file format that they would release the data file spec so that tools could be created to properly export existing data.

Here is also a SourceForge project for exporting MsMoney data in other formats: http://sunriise.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Sunriise opens the money file unchanged.  I ran it on Ubuntu 14.04 and it opened the file and allowed for export to csv and mdb.  I could not find the descriptions for transactions in the TRN table.

Comment: @AntoniosHadjigeorgalis if you mean memo for transaction it is 15th column in TRN table named mMemo

Answer (score 1):

There is a "[Class to transform an OFX (Microsoft Money) file into a DataSet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14386/Class-to-transform-ofx-Microsoft-Money-file-into-D)" on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/).

Comment: @RichB - to earn my cleanup badge.

Comment: OFX is not MS Money, so this is really not relevant at all.

Answer (score 1):

OFX has nothing to do with MS Money data file (mny).
OFX is an open standard based on sgml or xml depending on OFX version, MNY is a proprietary binary format.
MS Money can import OFX files but that's all.

If the requirement is to import only once then export from Money to csv or qif and process the exported files. Same applies to Quicken.

Money Sunset is free.

Answer (score 1):

This tool is free and will perform a more comprehensive export of Microsoft Money data.  I don't think it can be used programatically though.  http://www.ultrasoft.com/MoneyLink/overview.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a UK version, try http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26915